# Counting words with indexof

Tags: java, indexof

I have to count the first 1o words in a blog entry that is being read in... but my code will not allow this to happen.  I cannot use .split or string isempty or arrays... which leaves me with indexof and substrings.  my code right now only gets the first 3 words... any help for me out there.....

Here is what I have to use....

String getSummary() method
1.  Returns up to the first ten words of the entry as a summary of the entry.  If the entry has 10 words or less, the method returns the entire entry.
2.  Possible logic - The String classes' indexOf method can find the position of a space. Use this along with a looping construct to find the first 10 words.

```
public class BlogEntry 
{
    private String username;
    private Date dateOfBlog;
    private String blog;

    public BlogEntry() 
    {
        username = "";
        dateOfBlog = new Date();
        blog = "";
    }

    public BlogEntry(String sName, Date dBlogDate, String sBlog)
    {
        username = sName;
        dateOfBlog = dBlogDate;
        blog = sBlog;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBlog()
    {
        return dateOfBlog;
    }

    public String getBlog()
    {
        return blog;
    }

    public void setUsername(String sName)
    {
        username = sName;
    }

    public void setDateOfBlog(Date dBlogDate)
    {
        dateOfBlog.setDate(dBlogDate.getMonth(), dBlogDate.getDay(), dBlogDate.getYear());
    }

    public void setBlog(String sBlog)
    {
        blog = sBlog;
    }

    public String getSummary()
    {
        String summary = "";
        int position;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int last;

        position = blog.indexOf(" ");
        while (position != -1 && wordCount < 10)
        {
            summary += blog.substring(start, position) + " ";
            start = position + 1;
            position = blog.indexOf(" ", position + 1);
            wordCount++;
        }

        return summary;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Author: " + this.getUsername() + "\n\n" + "Date posted: " + this.getDateOfBlog() + "\n\n" + "Text body: " + this.getBlog();
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this? (Java?) *Why* can't you use those methods?

Comment: sorry yes it is Java...

Comment: I have knowledge of those methods from research but because this is for a class I cannot go beyond what we have covered... I have been working on this forever it seems and just cant figure out what i have done wrong... .split seems the simplest ut again I cannot go beyond what we have covered. :( @NathanTuggy

Comment: Show us what `blog` is set to when you call `getSummary()`

Comment: blog can be any string of any length.... for example "this program is pissing me off!" could be the string and my code is only pulling This Program is which is why I am needing help

Comment: I'm asking because I'd like to test your code against your input to see if I can reproduce what you're seeing.  Unless you've actually tried "this program is pissing me off!" and seen it only pull the first 3 words this doesn't help.

Comment: I have tried and that is what i got! @CandiedOrange

Comment: The close reason given is wrong.  Goldie gave a clear problem statement. "I have to count the first 1o words in a blog entry that is being read in."  And she gave a specific problem: "only gets the first 3 words" The issue was that this is true only with specific input: 4 words. If given 6 it gets 5. My compiler was nice enough to sort that out.  Sure it's past when reopening the question will do much good but this is teaching Goldie the wrong thing about stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    BlogEntry be = new BlogEntry("" , new Date(), "this program is pissing me off!");
    System.out.println( be.getSummary() );        
}
```

Produces this output:

```
this program is pissing me
```

Which is not 3 words, it's 5.  You should have 6. And this makes your bug much easier to understand.  You're experiencing a typical [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).  You are only appending and counting words that come before spaces.  That leaves the last word out since it doesn't appear before a space, only after the last space.

Here's some code close to what your started with that can see all 6 words:

```
public String getSummary()
{
    if (blog == null) 
    {
        return "<was null>";
    }

    String summary = "";
    int position;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int last;

    position = blog.indexOf(" ");
    while (position != -1 && wordCount < 10)
    {
        summary += blog.substring(start, position) + " ";
        start = position + 1;
        position = blog.indexOf(" ", position + 1);
        wordCount++;
    }
    if (wordCount < 10) 
    {
        summary += blog.substring(start, blog.length());
    }

    return summary;
}
```

which when tested with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] testStrings = {
          null //0
        , ""
        , " "
        , "  "
        , " hi"
        , "hi "//5
        , " hi "
        , "this program is pissing me off!"
        , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
        , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 "
        , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"//10
        , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 "
        , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"
        , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 "
        , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12"
        , "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 "//15
    };

    ArrayList<BlogEntry> albe = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String test : testStrings) {
        albe.add(new BlogEntry("" , new Date(), test));
    }

    testStrings[0] = "<was null>";

    for (int i = 0; i < albe.size(); i++ ) {
        assert(albe.get(i).getSummary().equals(testStrings[Math.min(i,11)]));
    }

    for (BlogEntry be : albe)
    {
        System.out.println( be.getSummary() );        
    }
}
```

will produce this:

```
<was null>



 hi
hi 
 hi 
this program is pissing me off!
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Also, I don't know where you're importing `Date` from but neither `import java.util.Date;` nor `import java.sql.Date;` will make your code error free.  I had to comment out your `setDate` code.

If your instructor will allow it, you can of course try the ideas in these other answers but I thought you'd like to know what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how efficient it would be, but could you just trim the string down each time you take index of? For example:

Contents of tempBlog:
This is a test
is a test
a test
test

Contents of summary:
This
is
a
test

```
public String getSummary()
{
    String summary = "";
    int wordCount = 0;
    int last;
    //Create a copy so you don't overwrite original blog
    String tempBlog = blog;

    while (wordCount < 10)
    {
        //May want to check if there is actually a space to read. 
        summary += tempBlog.substring(0, tempBlog.indexOf(" ")) + " ";
        tempBlog = tempBlog.substring(tempBlog.indexOf(" ")+1);
        wordCount++;
    }

    return summary;
}
```

Comment: no that is neither efficient or hat I am looking to do.  I want the first 10 words to print out.

Comment: @goldieAnneJohnson, Sorry. I had a typo. The corrected function works.

Answer (score 0):

`String.indexOf` aswell provides an overload that allows searching from a specific point (link to the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)). Using this method it's pretty simple:

```
public int countWort(String in , String word){
    int count = 0;

    int index = in.indexOf(word);

    while(index != -1){
        ++count;

        index = in.indexOf(word , index + 1);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this logic a try...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "This one sentence has exactly 10 words in it ok";

    int wordIndex = 0;
    int spaceIndex = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;
    while (wordCount < 1 && spaceIndex != -1) {
        spaceIndex = data.indexOf(" ", wordIndex);
        System.out.println(spaceIndex > -1 
                ? data.substring(wordIndex, spaceIndex)
                : data.substring(wordIndex));

        // The next word "should" be right after the space
        wordIndex = spaceIndex + 1;
        wordCount++;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
This
one
sentence
has
exactly
10
words
in
it
ok
```

### UPDATE

Is `regex` not an option?  With `regex` you can try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(data);

    int wordCount = 0;
    while (matcher.find() && wordCount < 10) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
        wordCount++;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
The
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
The
```

The regex is returning words with the following characters [a-zA-Z_0-9]

Comment: That did the same thing I had happen with my other code... it takes the last (10th) word and drops it if there is no space.

Comment: @GoldieAnneJohnson See updates to the first answer. Is Regex not an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can find the index of the first 10 words by checking if the character is a space character. Here is an example:

```
public class FirstTenWords
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String sentence = "There are ten words in this sentence, I want them to be extracted";
        String summary = firstOf( sentence, 10 );
        System.out.println( summary );
    }

    public static String firstOf( String line, int limit )
    {
        boolean isWordMode = false;
        int count = 0;
        int i;
        for( i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ )
        {
            char character = line.charAt( i );
            if( Character.isSpaceChar( character ) )
            {
                if( isWordMode )
                {
                    isWordMode = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if( !isWordMode )
                {
                    isWordMode = true;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if( count >= limit )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return line.substring( 0, i );
    }
}
```

Output on my laptop:

```
There are ten words in this sentence, I want
```